# Magento test automation frame work for a custom module

Tags: unit-testing, magento, automated-tests, mtaf

I have wrote a custom module in my magento store for skip chekout process. I need to test this module with my **Magento Test Automation Framework(MTAF)**.

Is there any option to test my custom module? Suggest me to test a custom module with **MTAF**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add your testcases under the required module under the testsuite and provide the file name in the phphunit.xml to specify it as the file being under test.